# onclick to trigger on specific tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a section in a page which has images and a button which triggers a modal via bootstrap and on the button I have an onclick event which shows the image header by overwriting the modal's default header text and there are 4-5 images with different header name.

But when I use the event handler it shows the header name of the first image and does not update the header when I click on the second image, I know I can achieve it by assigning unique event handlers to each button and so on but if there is a way to do it with just one event hander on all the buttons as in the "content should be updated based on the particular image's text"

**JS**

```
function modalPreview() {
    modalTitle.innerHTML = header.innerHTML;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="modalTest">
   <div class="modal fade" id="showModalTest">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal Title</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
               <span>&times; </span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/950x350" alt="product-image-stretch" class="img-fluid" id="modal-images" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `modalTitle` in your HTML? Also, can you post more of your HTML?

Comment: its referring to the modal title I didn't include it.    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Modal Title</h5>

Comment: Edit your question to include a fuller example of the HTML, please (don't post it in a comment)

Comment: Please provide the full HTML and JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not posted what is triggering you modal, I assume you have a button somewhere in your code, with `onclick` listener.

Since you are using Bs modal, you will surely have jQuery loaded on your page, so why not usign BS events and a bit of jQuery?

```
$('#modalTest').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('.modal-title').text("New modal Title");
});
```

If you have one trigger button for each image, I would suggest doing this instead:

```
$('.my_btn').on('click', function(){
    var new_title = $(this).closest('.image_and_button_container').find('.header_value').text();  //get your new header
    $('#modalTest .modal-title').text(new_title);         //set it
    $('#modalTest').modal('show');                        //and trigger modal
});
```

Check [BS modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) for more info